# Can I use Spring Security 3.0.7 with Spring 3.0.2?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security. When I downloaded it, I saw "Spring Security 3.0.7 requires a minimum of Spring 3.0.6 and Java 5.", this warning made me wonder if I can use it in my project based on Spring 3.0.2 and if I should wait for some troubles with this combination of versions. I suppose, I will also try using Security 3.0.2 with Spring 3.0.2, still I'm interested if 0.0.4 difference would bring problems.

Comment: any good reason for not upgrading to 3.0.6?

Comment: Not a single reason... Probably, I will in a short time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if there is a minimum version specified then there is a good reason for that. Whether you are affected or not will depend on what your application does.

You should generally be using the latest versions of both, as otherwise there's a good chance your application will be vulnerable to [various security vulnerabilities](http://www.springsource.com/security/spring-framework) (which you should monitor if you have an app in production).

Note that there is no direct link between the version numbers of Spring Framework and Spring Security. Using Spring Security 3.0.2 is a bad idea and you should really upgrade instead.